# How to upgrade symfony from 1.1.9 to 2 or 3?

Tags: symfony, symfony1, upgrade

My current working project is an old project (written on 2008). It uses symfony 1.1.9 which is stable version that time.

I have explored on upgrade symfony 1.1.9 to latest version. But couldn't get any documentation related on that. Please help on the same.

Comment: Symfony1 and Symfony2 are quite different beasts. There's no upgrade from one to the other, but a transition of your business logic from one framework to the other.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to **upgrade** symfony1 project to Symfony2/3. You need to do a **rewrite**.

Symfony2 was created as a completely new framework. Its concepts are fundamentally different from those known from symfony1. On the other hand, the difference between Symfony2 and Symfony3 is not that big. Backward compatibility is maintained and the update is very easy.

You need to assess if it's worth to do the rewrite. If the project is not heavily developed perhaps it's better to keep it on the old platform.

Answer (score 2):

there is a huge difference between `symfony 1` and `symfony 2`.
you will never find an easy way to make an easy update.

if you want to remain with `1.x` branch, my advice will be to update to `symfony 1.4.20`the last stable version on `symfony 1`.

but if you have the time and energy, I think that you have to extract database schema from the the actual project and build a new project base on `symfony 2.8`the last stable version for branch `2.x`